# Close a child window of an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html

I have a (sandboxed) IFRAME that opens a child window:

```
var childWindow = window.open("http://...", "_new").
```

How do I later close this window (from code running in the IFRAME)?

Calling `childWindow.close` works in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Or is there a way of closing the window by itself.

Comment: So you try to call `childWindow` from the `iframe`? But the `iframe` doesn't know about `childWindow`, unless you defined it there too.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it, the window.close() method works for me, also in Google Chrome:

```
var childWindow = window.open("", "_new");
// do something
childWindow.close();
```

You can also close the popup itself with `self.close()`

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://localhost:8000/loginComplete.html?code=7a02c46e-9489-48db-ba19-19cb4b6d6fd0' from frame with URL 'http://localhost:8000/sidebar.html'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

The child window (in Chrome) can close itself via

```
window.open("_blank", "_self").close();
```